# Table in a two column page

Tags: tables, two-column

I'am trying to do a table in a two column page, the table is wide. So I try with this code, but the problem is that the text within the table are align on the right.. Can I change it to the left align?
Thank you

```
\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{1}{r}@{}}
\toprule
 we must bare+in+mind the community as+a+whole. \\
 nous devons prendre+en+considération la communauté dans+son+ensemble.\\
 \midrule
  mr+president I wish+to+congratulate mrs+poulen on her report.\\
  monsieur+le+président je tiens+à+féliciter madame+poulen    sur+son+rapport.\\
   \bottomrule                             
   \end{tabular*}
   \caption{Exemples de phrases du corpus d'apprentissage \label{phraseapp}}
   \end{table*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using `r` (right align) as a column specifier. Use `l` (left align) instead.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{1}{l}@{}}
\toprule
 we must bare+in+mind the community as+a+whole. \\
 nous devons prendre+en+considération la communauté dans+son+ensemble.\\
\midrule
 mr+president I wish+to+congratulate mrs+poulen on her report.\\
 monsieur+le+président je tiens+à+féliciter madame+poulen    sur+son+rapport.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
   \caption{Exemples de phrases du corpus d'apprentissage \label{phraseapp}}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]